# Custom post type posts aren't showing up on the category pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a child theme for a client and making some new post types. Everything works great so far, except that the posts in the custom post type are not showing up underneath the categories page; although they are in that category.

Here is my code for creating the custom post type...

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function directory_listing() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Directory Items', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Directory Item', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Directory Listing', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'      => __( 'Directory', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Directory:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Listings', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Listing', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'            => __( 'New Listing', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Listing', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Listing', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Listing', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Listing', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'directory_listings', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Directory Listing', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'post-formats', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-flag',
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 'directory_listings', $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'directory_listing', 0 );
}
```

The part I don't understand is that when I go to the actual post in the custom post type the "view post" url I get is something like...

http://otpguide.dev/directory_listings/another-place/

However, the category url for the category that particular post is marked under is something like...

http://otpguide.dev/category/directory/alpharetta/

Shouldn't the custom post type have a url more like...

http://otpguide.dev/category/directory/alpharetta/another-place ??

Why don't my posts show up under the categories page?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

Custom post types aren't included in archive.php unless you specify them to be. I added this snippet and it worked perfectly.

```
// allow custom post types in archive
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {
if( !is_admin() ) {
    if ( !is_post_type_archive() && $query->is_archive() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'your-custom-post-type', 'another_custom_post_type' ) );
    }
    return $query;
    }
}
```

Apparently the same thing is true for search.php; you also have to have ''exclude_from_search' => false,' declared when you register your custom post type

```
// add custom post types to search
// Define what post types to search
function searchAll( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'feed', 'your-custom-post-type', 'another_custom_post_type'));
}
return $query;
}

// The hook needed to search ALL content
add_filter( 'the_search_query', 'searchAll' );
```